# how to deploy java EE listener using @WebListener

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to implement a new listener (using the servlet 3.0 spec).

```
@WebListener
public class LoadingManager implements ServletContextListener 
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {

    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {


    }

}
```

I package the listener in a jar and I want to know which is the better deployment mode

- Put the jar on the tomcat/lib
- Put the jar inside webapps/My-Application/lib

If I deploy the jar under the tomcat/lib, how much time the method **contextInitialized** will be performed (knowing that I have a set of webapplicatio deployed on my tomcat instance)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Better to add it in the webapps/My-Application/lib so that it can be used based on individual application and not for all the applications

Comment: @NikhilTalreja post that as an answer as it is the -only- correct way to go. A listener is for one specific web application so putting it in tomcat/lib is not only architecturally wrong, I wouldn't know how you can ever make it work as you cannot reference any application specific classes or resources in it! It would live in entirely the wrong classloader.

Comment: It works put I can't control how many time the listener is invoked

Answer (score 3):

Better to add it in the webapps/My-Application/lib so that it can be used based on individual application and not for all the applications

Even Gimby has some good points in the comment.